# should I close mysql_connection after every query in php cli?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I wrote a php cli script to be as an little online game host.(Yes I know it's weird.)

Mysql query is often used in this script. I'm afraid the connection will hold resource, so every time I need run a query, I write code like this:

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
    mysql_select_db("xxx",$con);
    mysql_query($sql)
    $con = null;
```

It's really frustrating when there's a lot of it. #_#

My question is should I use only one connection, and use it everywhere in the script, and set it null when exit? I think there should be some connection pool with Zend engine.

PS.
 Each script's in charge of one play room, so there may up to 100 at a time, and echo may last for 24 hour.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The script you wrote is a server I assume? It's not "weird", but can you explain in detail how many of these are you running? One or multiple?

Comment: Do you mean you're afraid the connection will timeout because the script runs for a very long time? (If yes, how long?) Also, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, don't use them, use PDO or Zend DB instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience there is no signifficat difference in resources if you use one connection for one pass of the script or connect+disconnect everytime you need mysql. The "only" difference is in the number of lines of PHP file.

I use function to connect and disconnect:

```
function mysql_start($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass){
    mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die ('Error #10020_1!');
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
}

function mysql_stop(){
    mysql_close();
}
```

Then I just call the function connect in the beginning of the file and stop at the end..

Also, just to make thing clean I don't use "mysql_select_db" function. I always select the database in FROM part of SQL query like:

```
SELECT
    A.something AS something,
    B.something_else AS something_else,
    ...
FROM database_name.table_name AS A, other_database_name.other_table_name AS B 
WHERE 
    ....
```

But to answer your question - after some testing in my environment and in my type of scripts of data handeling there was no difference in resource allocation or in speed..

Answer (score 5):

The connection **is supposed** to hold the resource. That's what you want. If you constantly allocate/deallocate the connection, you're doing more work, every time.

If you have a long running process that has to talk to MySQL constantly, open up one connection and keep it open. It's called a persistent connection. Nothing bad will happen. But if you constantly open/close the connection, you're doing the TCP handshake, forcing the OS to allocate file descriptor and CPU has to do more work because OS constantly creates a new thread for each connection you create/destroy. That's extremely wasteful.

However, keeping a connection open isn't sufficient. Connections can die. You need a database connection wrapper that can determine whether connection is established and if not - establish one. The same wrapper should take care of disconnect/reconnect.

In other words, do not close the connection. Rewrite your code in such a way that you can invoke a function/object that takes care of connect/reconnect and returns the connection resource that you use.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: consider using `mysqli_`instead of `mysql_` as the mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP5.5.

Next: Each time you are calling `mysqli_connect` a connection to the database-server is established. That can be almost instantaneously when the Database-Server is on the same machne and the connection to the database is configured via sockets. But when the databaseserver is located on a different machine it can take a while. So when you open a lot of connections (after closing the old ones) that might make your application a bit slower.

So I'd always opt for opening a conection once at the start and close it after all queries have been processed.